# Generlized IP Canonicalization Solution Within .htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I am looking for a generalized IP canonicalization solution that would not hard code IP address in my htaccess file.  I generally run my applications on amazon EC2 instances and IP addresses frequently change.  I'd hate to have to manually update htaccess every time it does so.  So specifically, I am looking for htaccess rules that would match pages accessed via ip address and perform a 301 redirect to the actual domain.

Answer (score 0):

I’m going to assume you don’t have any subdomains. The following should do the trick:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
# 1
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} .
# 2
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.domain\.com$
# 3
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.domain.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

This will redirect requests for anything<sup>1</sup> other than the actual domain<sup>2</sup> for all resources<sup>3</sup>.

**EDIT**: For subdomains, then the following should work:

```
# If it's one of the domains of the IP address …
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain\.com [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^111\.222\.222\.111
# … then redirect request for all resources.
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: I do have subdomains. I actually have a wildcard entry in DNS. So I would have to use some sort of regex to check for an IP pattern and redirect to the canonical domain.

Comment: @VinnyD In that case, you can change to condition to check for the domain or the IP address and then redirect. I’ve amended the above with the example.

Comment: Sorry I wasn't clear.  The issue is that the IP address of the amazon load balancer can change without notice.  Is there any way to match IP using a regex condition to catch any possible IP?

Comment: Try `^(?:(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.){3}(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)$` rather than `^111\.222\.222\.111`

Answer (score 0):

Had you considered using some variety of [Dynamic DNS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_DNS) instead? That would let the IP addresses change frequently while maintaining the same DNS names.

Comment: The reason I'd like to do this is for SEO purposes so I don't get dinged for duplicate content.